# find first character of string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oop

In particular string, I have to compare that if the first character 
    of the string is "x"(any) then return all string otherwise blank and  other condition is if there is forth character is  "-" then return the string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace @string
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myString = "bhargav m patel".Trim();

            Console.Write("Type a char : ");
            string mychar = Console.ReadLine();

            if (myString.StartsWith("[a-zA-Z]").Equals(mychar))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with this code?

Comment: I can't able compare the first character.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (myString.StartsWith(myChar))`?

Comment: didn't try that.. will check. tnx @ken

Comment: None of the string methods support Regex, hence your issue. Just do StartsWith("x")

Comment: How does the first condition associated with the second one? and what does forth character means? or you mean the fourth character?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried this out and it worked perfeclty. Does it fit in your situation?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myString = "bhargav m patel".Trim();

    Console.Write("Type a char : ");
    string mychar = Console.ReadLine();

    if (myString.StartsWith(mychar))
        Console.WriteLine("true");
    else 
       Console.WriteLine("false");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I got what u want, but:
If you want to compare string first char and the char the user have input, u could do:

```
if (myString.StartsWith(mychar))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
```